# Issue in react with an if / else

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

What am I missing to make it work? 
I suppose the answer is very easy, but really, I'm starting in
React and still do not know why it does not work. If anyone knows, I am very grateful.

Thanks.

```
    import React from 'react';

    var a=30;
    var b=20;

    function App() {
      return (
        <div>
        <h1>if or else</h1>
        <c/>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;

    function c(a,b) {
      if (a >= b){ 
      return (
        <div> 
        <h2> A is greater than B</h2>
        </div>
        );
     }
      else {
         return (
          <div> 
           <h2>B is greater than A</h2>
          </div>
        );
     }
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What exactly happens for you when this code is run? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: You should put else if (b>a) instead of else there

Comment: Does this answer your question https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html ?

Comment: Another way to do it https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-swanson-vggnl?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you need to do it like this

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
    <h1>if or else</h1>
    <C a={20} b={30}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

function C({a, b}) {
  if (a >= b){ 
  return (
    <div> 
    <h2> A is greater than B</h2>
    </div>
    );
 }
  else {
     return (
      <div> 
       <h2>B is greater than A</h2>
      </div>
    );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, react components need to start with a capital letter, otherwise the React renderer will treat it as plain HTML.

Change your function declaration to:

```
function C(a,b) {}
```

And change your JSX where you call that component to:

```
<C/>
```

---

Second, a component must take a single argument (the props), but your component takes two arguments. And then where you call the component, you don't currently pass in any props.

So make your component take props as a single object:

```
function C(props) {
  if (props.a >= props.b) {
    //...
```

And now pass the props in where you invoke the component:

```
<C a={a} b={b} />
```